# The SUM() is counting all the values, instead of the ones that meet the condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query to write:

> Knowing that a team will earn at least the market value (WartoscRynkowa) of a given
> player from the sale of a player and knowing the amount of his
> transfer (KwotaTransferu), calculate how much the team will earn or lose by selling
> players with the highest chance of transfer (> = 2) (SzansaNaTransfer), provide data for
> each a player who meets the above condition (player data, amount) and
> provide the value for all of them together;

Here are the tables:
[image]

I did a query as the following one:

```
SELECT *, Imie+' '+Nazwisko AS ImieNazwisko,
                                            (SELECT SUM(WartoscRynkowa) -SUM(KwotaTransferu)
                                            FROM Beata.dane
                                            ) AS Result
FROM Beata.dane AS D
JOIN Beata.team AS T
ON D.NumerKoszulki = T.NumerKoszulki
WHERE SzansaNaTransfer >= 1
```

[image]

**The Result 130 is wrong, because it counts also the players. It should be 33, because the sum of WartoscRynkowa(market value) is 215 minus KwotaTransferu(amount of transer) - 182 = 33**

**Why the query counts also the amount of the players that don't meet the condition ">=1"**

EDIT: I've updated the query and getting the following result. How to summarize the total value in the other column (I mean summarize all the Results)?

```
SELECT T.Imie, T.Nazwisko,
                                            (SELECT SUM(WartoscRynkowa) - SUM(KwotaTransferu)
                                            FROM Beata.dane NAD
                                            WHERE NAD.WartoscRynkowa = D.WartoscRynkowa
                                            ) AS Result
FROM Beata.dane AS D
JOIN Beata.team AS T
ON D.NumerKoszulki = T.NumerKoszulki
WHERE SzansaNaTransfer >= 2
```

[image]

Comment: Edit your question and include the query as *text*.  As an image, it is not readable.

Comment: Your subquery sums every row in Beata.dane for every row in your join. That is why it generates the same number for every joined row. You probably meant to correlate that subquery. Search the internet on the term "correlated subquery" to find tutorials that cover this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the question rather hard to follow, not understanding what the column names are.  I don't think you need aggregation to solve this, but you need a way to calculate the total -- and window functions are one method:

```
SELECT (t.Imie + ' ' + t.Nazwisko) AS ImieNazwisko,
       (WartoscRynkowa - KwotaTransferu) as Result,
       SUM(WartoscRynkowa - KwotaTransferu) OVER () as overall_total
FROM Beata.dane D JOIN 
     Beata.team AS T
     ON D.NumerKoszulki = T.NumerKoszulki
WHERE SzansaNaTransfer >= 2;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon, however I got the error "Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type tinyint."  `(NumerKoszulki tinyint NOT NULL FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES Beata.team(NumerKoszulki),
KrajPochodzenia varchar(10) NOT NULL,
ReprezentatKraju char(1),
PoprzedniKlubKraj varchar(10) NOT NULL,
KwotaTransferu tinyint NOT NULL,
WartoscRynkowa tinyint NOT NULL);`

Comment: Convert the values in the arithmetic expression to something more useful, such as an int.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.team,sum(a.MARKET_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY TEAM) as totalMarketValue, 
sum(a.TRANSFER_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY TEAM) As TotalTransferAmount,
(sum(a.TRANSFER_AMOUNT) OVER (PARTITION BY TEAM) - sum(a.MARKET_VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY TEAM)) AS TEAM_EARNINGS
FROM A
JOIN B
ON a.ID = b.ID
where b.TRANSFER_CHANCE >= 2
```

If i understand correctly you want the earnings for each team.
Sum market value and Transfer amount for each team and subtract the 2.

| team | totalMarketValue | TotalTransferAmount | TEAM_EARNINGS |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Portugal | 40 | 50 | 10 |
| Ukraina | 3 | 9 | 6 |
| wychowanek | 80 | 0 | -80 |